# Repeating SSRS Matrix Column Headers SSRS 2015

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I have an Excel Pivot that I want to reproduce in a SSRS Matrix.

The Excel Pivot looks like this:

[image: Excel Pivot]

Notice the first column header "Full Face Masks" repeats on each column.

My SSRS matrix looks like this:

[image: SSRS Matrix]

Notice how "Full Face Masks" does NOT repeat, despite repeating turned on.

As suggested, I've added an image of the Design View:

[image: Design View]

I've read through DOZENS of answers/sites related to repeating column headers.

I've even gone through the XML line-by-line to see if I can find an answer, but no luck.

So, in SSRS 2015, how do I make my report look like the Excel Pivot image.  I KNOW it's possible -- I've seen it done but yeah... I can't figure it out.

```
[1 - Excel Pivot]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVNnG.png
[2 - SSRS Matrix]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKmq7.png
[3 - Design View]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/du4f8.png
```

Comment: Is your column header in your column group? It might be above - out of the group. If not, a pic of your design view might help to see what the issue is.

Comment: Right after I added the edit based on this comment it clued me in to the issue.  I just got it worked out, so KUDOS to you, sir.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem which occurs when you use groups. You need to do the following thing to resolve this:

1. Add a row above the group, this row will be created as outside the group. Put the values that need to be repeated in the matrix and shown on the report.
2. Remove Group columns from the matrix. **Do not remove the group, only remove group column from the matrix.**